# Integrating Differentials of Two Variables

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, physics, differential

In a thermodynamics text I'm reading, the author says the following,

"The integral of the perfect differential $dz = y\,dx + (x+c) \,dy \; (\mathrm{where} \; z = xy + cy)$ from point (0,0) to pint $(a,b)$, over the path $(0,0)$ to $(0,b)$ to $(a,b)$ is

$$ c\cdot \int_0^b dy + b\cdot \int_0^adx = cb + ab. \quad (1)"$$

Later in the text - and presumably using the same integration rule - says the following (here I'm paraphrasing),

"Integrating $dS = \frac{3}{2} nR/T) dT + (nR/V) dV$ gives
$$ S = nR \ln[(T/T_0)^{3/2}(V/V_0)] + S_0 \quad (2)$$

where $S = S_0$ when $T = T_0$ and $V = V_0.$"

My question is - where does this come from? I've taken two semesters of analysis and I haven't seen anything like this. In the case of (1), wouldn't one have to integrate the right-hand side with respect to both $x$ and $y$? If so, the resultant should have two terms, each of which being functions of both $x$ and $y$. Why can I integrate each term separately with respect to its variable? Where's the justification?

Comment: you integrate along the path from x=0 to x=0 und y=0 to y=b . I think you just did not put the path in the integral. Same in integrating along a path for S so there I do not realize the path taken  probably from T0 to T and V0 to V?

Answer (score 1):

The integral of a one-form $Pdx + Qdy$ over a curve $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, parameterized for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, is by definition
$$ \int_\gamma (P dx + Q dy) = \int_0^1 \left(P(x(t),y(t)) x'(t) + Q(x(t),y(t)) y'(t) \right) dt $$
In other words, it is technically an integral over $t$, the parameter defining the curve. In your example (1), the curve $\gamma$ consists of two line segments which are horizontal and vertical. For the first part, from $(0,0)$ to $(0,b)$, you can take $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t)) = (0, t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq b$. In this case, $y(t) = t$, so the integral can be thought of as being over the variable "$y$". Similarly, the second segment is horizontal, so $x(t) = t$ in that case. Hopefully this answers your question:

> Why can I integrate each term separately with respect to its variable? Where's the justification?

On a side note: computing this integral explicitly is unnecessary, since by the fundamental theorem,
$$ \int_\gamma dz = z(a,b) - z(0,0) $$

Answer (score 0):

The entropy $S$ of a system is a *state function* and so the differential $dS$ is an [exact differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential), given by:

$$ dS = \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_V dT + \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right)_T dV $$

Or, for ideal gases:

$$ dS = \frac{C_V}{T} dT + \frac{nR}{V} dV $$

We can verify it is an exact differential by the symmetry in second derivates, i.e. $\frac{\partial S}{\partial T \partial V} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial V \partial T} = 0$. Since $S$ is a state function it takes the form of differentiable scalar function $S(V,T)$ and so we may write:

$$ \Delta S = \int_i^f dS = \int_C \nabla S(\textbf{r}) \cdot d \textbf{r} = \int_C \nabla S(\textbf{r}(t)) \cdot \textbf{r}'(t) dt $$

Which is a line integral along some curve $C$ represented by $\textbf{r}(t)$. Now $\nabla S$ is conservative, as shown by the symmetry of second derivatives, and so the integral is path independent according to the [gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem). Since the integral is path independent we can integrate along any path we like, e.g. integrating $\frac{C_V}{T}$ at constant $V$ and $\frac{nR}{V}$ at constant $T$. This means we may write:

$$ \Delta S = \int_i^f \frac{C_V}{T} dT + \int_i^f \frac{nR}{V} dV $$

And so we conclude:

$$ \Delta S = C_V \ln \frac{T}{T_0} + nR \ln \frac{V}{V_0}$$

Or for monatomic gases:

$$ \Delta S =  nR \ln \left( \left( \frac{T}{T_0} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \frac{V}{V_0} \right)$$